# Scrolling is working but Click() is not working

Tags: selenium, appium-android

```
AndroidElement list = (AndroidElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("Sample Xpath"));

MobileElement listGroup = list.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("+"new UiSelector().text(\"SampleText\"));

assertNotNull(listGroup.getLocation();

listGroup.click();
```

Here I'm able to Scroll the required area. But the `Click()` is not working.

Any one have idea?

I've tried with `driver.getPagesource();` to refresh but it is not working.

Comment: Induce _ExplicitWait_ for the element to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidElement list = (AndroidElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("Sample Xpath")).click();

```
MobileElement listGroup = list.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("+"new UiSelector().text(\"SampleText\")).click();

assertNotNull(listGroup.getLocation();
```

Use these commands.

Comment: Hi @Nauman Malik,  i'm unable to give the .click(); at the end of line. And errors are occurred while giving the .click(); at EOL. Please provide me another solution.

Comment: Hi. It normally works fine. Please check if you have included all the Selenium JARS in your project. I can't think of anything else other than this to click on a component.Make sure the component you want to click is visible on the screen and you have given correct Xpaths and resource id's.